# regular expression clob field

Tags: regex, oracle, select, oracle10g

I have a question related to an regular expression in oracle 10.

Assuming I have a value like 123456;12345;454545 stored in a clob field, is there a way via an regular expression to only filter on the second pattern (12345) knowing that the value can be more then 5 digits but always occurs after the first semicolon and always has a trailing semicolon at the end?

Thanks a lot for your support in that matter,

Have a nice day,

Comment: Is your input pattern always going to have three numbers? As in three numbers separated by two semicolons? Or your input pattern can have an unlimited number of numbers separated by semicolons and you want the second number.

Comment: Either unlimited occurences of numbers with trailing semicolons. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

This query should give you your desired output.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR('123456;12345;454545;45634',';[0-9]+;'),';')
FROM dual;
```

Comment: +1 but: A) Optionally may be modified `[0-9]*` instead of `[0-9]+` to detect empty values.  B) It's possible to use `replace` instead of `regexp_replace` for a little speed-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can get filter any pattern using this query just change 2 to any value, but it should be less than or equal to the number of elements in the string

```
with tab(value) as
(select '123456;12345;454545' from dual)
select regexp_substr(value, '[^;]+', 1, 2) from tab;
```

Answer (score 0):

easily by one call:

```
select regexp_replace('123456;12345;454545','^[0-9]+;([0-9]+);.*$','\1')
from dual;
```

perhaps, regexp expression can be modified in a way of more good-looking or your business logic, but the idea, I think, is clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_substr(Col_name,';\d+;'),';','') from your_table;
```